# Editing an automated naming macro in excel (based on PC name and date, with variable save path)

Tags: excel, vba, save, attr, environ

I'm currently trying to get an excel file to save into YYYYMMDD_fixed name piece_INITIALS OF LAST PERSON TO EDIT.

I'm using Environ function to call the User's and PC's name in a cell that i've found can be used to add to the name.

The issues i'm trying to fix are:

1. how can i define the save path to work on any PC regardless of user name, as current path has Users/my name/ , and up to 4 people with different PCs and names will edit this file. it should just save on Desktop on any of the 4 PCs
2. how can i modify the

```
strFile = "C:\Users\me\Desktop\" & Format(dtDate, "ddmmyyyy") & ".xlsx"
```

part so  that it displays YYYYMMDD_name (i get this part ok) _ABC where ABC value is in cell A1 generated by the below attr function?

the function used is

```
Function attr(choice) As String
   Select Case (choice)
      Case "computer": attr = Environ("Computername")
      Case "user": attr = Environ("UserName")
   End Select
End Function
```

and the one i use to save (albeit a different format on a different file) is

```
Dim dtDate As Date
    dtDate = Date

    Dim strFile As String
    strFile = "C:\Users\me\Desktop\" & Format(dtDate, "ddmmyyyy") & ".xlsx"

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strFile, FileFormat _
    :=51, CreateBackup:=False
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! 
Programming is not my main job, just trying to automate bits where possible, so go easy on me please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like that will help:

```
Dim strFile As String, strUserName As String
Dim dtDate As Date

dtDate = Now
strUserName = attr("user")

strFile = "C:\Users\" & strUserName & "\Desktop\" & Format(dtDate, "ddmmyyyy") & "_" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value & ".xlsx"
MsgBox strFile
```

Note that I assigned the value of an active username to `strUserName` and I'm using it with your `strFile`. I also added `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value` to the code (change sheet name accordingly). The final result will look like that:

`C:\Users\username\Desktop\12082019_username.xlsx`

Comment: Thank you! That works brilliantly, my monday morning caffeine-UNinfused brain ignored the MsgBox strFile part and couldn't understand why the popup!

Extra candies for adding the sheet part, i actually need to pick a particular one out of 8 so thanks for thinking in advance!

Comment: No problem at all (I know a thing or two about caffeine :)). Feel free to upvote/accept the answer if it was useful - see: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: already voted, but seems it won't count due to my low/novice rating. didn't know about the checkmark thingy! :)

Comment: Thanks! The more points you get, the more options/privileges you will have. Have fun & also try to help other people with their questions. Btw welcome to the forum :)